# Why does name textfield not presented in drupal comment form?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

In this my new site   while entering comments why only Subject textfield is presented to the user? I need Name text field too. How can I do it?
This is sample comment page [site link](http://www.maternityleaverules.in/comment/reply/6#comment-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under *Administer » Content management » Content types* Choose the content type where you have these comments show up.

You will see a fieldset called "comment settings", underneath which you find a setting whether a user *must*, *may* or *may not* leave contact information.

Comment: but I don't want email id field to show up. I want only Name field. If I add Name field  using a module, will this Name be shown along with the comment?

Comment: You should ask that as a new question. Best done over at drupal.stackexchange.com because it is hardly programming related :)